# Генерация документа с учётом вписанных данных

Tags: javascript, html5

уважаемые разработчики. У меня нету проблемы, я просто хочу попросить у вас помощи в реализации одного сервиса.
Как мне реализовать на JavaScript обыкновенную генерацию документа, тоесть:
Пользователь вводит значения заданных параметров в полях (формах), затем нажимает кнопочку "сгенерировать", и у него генерируется текст (уже заготовленный = шаблон) или документ, в котором присутствуют вписанные им данные. Как мне это можно реализовать, или хотя бы как называется такой прием, чтобы я нашёл курсы в интернете? Я уже пытался искать такую фишку, но проблема в том, что практически во всех затрагивается серверная часть, и превращается такая процедура в довольно сложный механизм с участием других интересных языков на подобии PHP, C#, Ruby и .т.д.
Вот именно на JS можно сделать что-то похожее? Я видел такие процедуры на разных сайтах много раз, при этом никакой регистрацией и не пахло. Я мог спокойно зайти и сгенерировать документ со своими введёнными данными.
Буду очень благодарен даже за то, что потратили время и дочитали до этой строки.

Comment: 1) Слова "нету" не существует. 2) А какой такой документ должен генерировать код? 3) Как вы уже пытались это реализовать? Читали ли вы хоть какую-нибудь книгу/документацию/видеоурок(5+ часов) по JS?

Comment: Если вы не знали, серверная часть может работать и без "регистрации". Она может просто получать какие-то данные, на основе этого генерировать файл и отправить пользователю. Как раз что вам нужно, вам не кажется?